# Remove milli second from timstamp in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to remove millisecond from `21-02-14 10:41:08.000000000 PM`.

I try

```
select to_date('21-02-14 10:41:08.000000000 PM','DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS:SSSSS PM') from dual;
```

**error**:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select to_date('21-02-14 10:41:08.000000000 PM','DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS:PM') from dual
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required
01855. 00000 -  "AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: i want only 21-02-14 10:41:08  data in the above

Comment: Well you've got two problems, it seems: how to parse the data, and how to truncate to a second. What are you actually starting with - text or a timestamp field? If you're starting with a timestamp field, it's not clear why you're calling to_date at all.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying fractional seconds, but your format has "seconds past midnight" - which doesn't have 9 digits. You're also specifying a colon in your format string, when your data has a dot. Try:

```
select cast(to_timestamp('21-02-14 10:41:08.000000000 PM','DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS.FF9 PM') as date) from dual;
```

Comment: i am getting error   Error starting at line : 18 in command -
select to_date('21-02-14 10:41:08.000000000 PM','DD/MM/YY HH:MI:SS.FF9 PM') from dual
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Nanda: I hadn't noticed that your date format was broken too. Try with my amended format string.